# Initialising two dimensional array

Tags: visual-c++

How do I initialise a two dimensional array?

I keep getting an error - No initialiser provided for the reference member Matrices::array.

```
Matrices::Matrices()
{       
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
double** array = new double*[0]; 
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    array[i] = new double[0];
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        array[i][j] = 0;
}
```

I don't know I tried so many ways like:

```
double** array = new double*[0]; 
array[0] = new double[0];
array[0][0] = 0;
```

Comment: I compiled this in Visual Studio, changing "Matrices::Matrices()" to main (since I don't have the rest of your code). I don't get an error.  Looking at the array in the debugger was strange, because it's a 0x0 array and so there really are no members; I shifted it to a 2x2 array and everything worked well.

What compiler do you have, and can you provide us with a complete example that shows the problem?

Comment: I think I did solve it, thanks for the help. The problem was that in one of the code I defined it as double ** & array. :D